# My pages load slowly. Code needs to be faster any suggestions?

Tags: excel, vba

Background: This project is gets loaded into full screen maximized.To make it look good I took out the tabs, formula bar, headers and status bar. I created my own buttons customized from shapes. These do have some very attractive colors and 3D views and I am wondering it is my code or the shapes that cause it to load slowly. When I Click a button to change pages is when this happens. Initially I had the button macros simply changing the pages but I thought it was slow because i was using select code. worksheet.Activate and worksheets.range.select. And the code was in the worksheet private sub under the Activate event. Then I took the code from there removed the select criteria and it almost feels slower. Is there anything I can do to pick up speed? Thank you.

This Example shows how the buttons are positioned up top of each worksheet. There are 10 sheets with these buttons which are shapes.

[Example of 1 worksheet with Navigation Buttons on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QjNJ.png)
Here is the code im using now. This code is in public subs for a general module.

```
Sub StartPg()
'ChangePagesmacro
    With wsStart.Application 'initiate page loading
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'turn off calculations
        .ScreenUpdating = False 'turn off screen updates
        .EnableEvents = False 'disable events
        .Goto Reference:=wsStart.Range("A4"), Scroll:=True 'page starting point
        With .ActiveWindow
            If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False 'unfreeze panes to remove any jam up`enter code here`
            .SplitColumn = 0 'unsplit column to free up screen
            .SplitRow = 0 'unsplit row to free up screen
            .WindowState = xlMaximized 'maximize window
            .DisplayHeadings = False 'turn of page headings
            .DisplayFormulas = False ' hide formula bar
            .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False 'hide page tabs
            .DisplayGridlines = False 'hide gridlines
            .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True 'show scrollbar
            .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True 'show scrollbar
            .Zoom = 81 'zoom and area
            .ScrollColumn = 1 'scroll to top
            .ScrollRow = 1 'scroll to left
            .SplitColumn = 0 'split colum to be frozen
            .SplitRow = 3 'split row to be frozen
            .FreezePanes = True 'freeze panes
        End With
    End With
    With wsStart
        .ScrollArea = "SAStart" 'set user scroll area
        With .Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'turn on calculations
            .ScreenUpdating = True ' turn on screen updates
            .EnableEvents = True ' turn on events
            .DisplayFormulaBar = False 'No formula bar
            .DisplayStatusBar = False 'No status bar
            .DisplayFullScreen = True ' show full screen
        End With
    End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Shapes take time to get drawn on the Excel canvas so yes, they can slow down your code if you change the selection.

Comment: Thank you. would it help if I remove the 3D and flatten them out a little bit or should go to form controls. Acivex seemed alot slower.

Comment: Experiment! But anything you draw on the canvas takes time to render. You could revert to formatting cells so they look like buttons and use the selectionchange event. But you'll have to take into account people might inadvertently select more than a single cell

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will remove some of the polish from them and see if it helps. I was thinking that could have something to do with it.